# How to get position of top of text itself, rather than text element, in jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gd

I'm not sure if this is possible, but here goes:

I want to find the y co-ordinate of some text.  For my purposes, the y co-ordinate of the *element containing that text* does not suffice.  Here's why:

http://jsfiddle.net/3kh3p/

In the above jsfiddle are two characters, one in Georgia, one in Verdana.  They are both positioned absolutely with top:0.  As you can see, the Verdana character begins at a lower point than the Georgia character.

I need to get the y co-ordinate of the text itself, fairly accurately, because I am using that value to write text to an image using PHP's imagettftext function, and being 5 or 10 pixels out is not OK.

Is there a way?

Comment: In English we align letters to the bottom

Comment: @Joseph: In English we align letters to their *baseline*, which is not necessarily the bottom (think `g`, `q`, and other [descenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender)).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of would be to draw the text ([`fillText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas#fillText%28%29)) into a [`canvas` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element), and then query the element's [pixel data](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas) (`getImageData` and such) to find out where a given character actually starts vertically according to whatever criteria you want to use (e.g., do you want to ignore upward serifs or not, etc.). Not for the faint of heart, if there's any other way to achieve your overall goal, I'd look elsewhere.